# Combining the confidence intervals of beta and OR values

Tags: confidence-interval, delta-method

I'm doing Mendelian randomization by hand as my supervisor wants me to practice. Based off a paper I'm learning from there is an intermediate phenotype (IP|G): SD increase of iron due to a mutation = 0.37 (0.33-0.41). The same mutation causes a change in parkinsons disease (D|G): OR per allele = 0.97 (0.92-1.02).

I'm trying to get an estimate of the odds ratio for Parkinsons (D|G) per SD unit increase in iron.

The Wald statistic has given me the OR i.e.

```
ln(betaIV) = ln(ORpd) / IP|G
           = ln(0.97) / 0.37
    betaIV = exp(-.82) = 0.92 (which is what the paper gives)
```

But now I need to combine the confidence intervals. What I've tried:

D|G: convert OR to beta by taking nat log of all values = -0.03 (-0.083 - 0.02)[SE = 0.026 taken from CI]

IP|G: keep as change in number of SDs = 0.37 (0.33 - 0.41) [SE of 0.02 from CI]

Delta method:

[image: Taken from paper on MR]

```
var(BetaIV) = (var(D|G)x(E(D|G)) / (E(IP|G)^2) + ((E(D|G)^2) / ((E(IP|G)^4) x var(E(IP|G) - 0 (0 because covariant is unknown so the third term is ignored)
            = (0.026^2)(-0.03)/(0.37^2) + (-0.03^2)/(0.37^4).(0.02^2)(0.37)
            = -0.0001
```

I cannot take the root of var(B) to give me the SE and if I disregard the negative I get the wrong answer. I think I've gone about this wrong but I've gone through a lot of different sources and can't figure it out.

The answer I'm looking for is 0.92 (0.79 - 1.08), OR for Parkinsons per SD unit increase in iron.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my God I'm stupid. I was misreading the formula the whole time and considering var(E(""|G)) to mean (var)x(E(""|G)).

I have corrected it and am close enough to the answer to be happy. If you can still improve on what I'm doing I'd love to know.

```
var(BetaIV) = (var(D|G)x(E(D|G)) / (E(IP|G)^2) + ((E(D|G)^2) / ((E(IP|G)^4) x var(E(IP|G) - 0 (0 because covariant is unknown so the third term is ignored)
            = (0.026^2)/(0.37^2) + (-0.03^2)/(0.37^4).(0.02^2)
            = 0.0049
```

Take square root for SE:

```
sqr(0.0049) = 0.0698
```

Then multiply by Z(1.96) for CI:

```
0.0698 x 1.96 ~ 0.14
```

This gives me 0.92 (0.78 - 1.06)

Given the paper used software I think this is a reasonable result.